# What does this array syntax mean?

Tags: php

While looking at code online or as part of examples or tutorials, I sometimes see `some_function(array($this, 'something'))` what does that mean? I've never seen array syntax like that and it really confuses me.

One example is this code from [a comment in the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php):

```
<?php

    class ClassAutoloader {
        public function __construct() {
            spl_autoload_register(array($this, 'loader'));
        }
        private function loader($className) {
            echo 'Trying to load ', $className, ' via ', __METHOD__, "()\n";
            include $className . '.php';
        }
    }

    $autoloader = new ClassAutoloader();

    $obj = new Class1();
    $obj = new Class2();

?>
```

Can someone please explain what that syntax means?

Comment: It's the syntax for an object/method callable rather than a simple function callable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a PHP `callable`. It means call the method `loader` on the object `$this`.

Here is a link with more information: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php

Comment: Then is there a difference between writing `spl_autoload_register(array($this, 'loader'));` and `spl_autoload_register($this->loader($className));`? What are the benefits of writing it as it is in the example code?

Comment: Unless `$this->loader($className)` returns a `callable`, you can't call it like that. `spl_autoload_register` requires a `callable` as its first parameter.

Answer (score 1):

This is the usual array-syntax in PHP. You're probably confused, because it is not saved in a variable but passed directly. To clarify this,

```
spl_autoload_register(array($this, 'loader'));
```

is equivalent to

```
$array = array($this, 'loader');
spl_autoload_register($array);
```

and to

```
$array = array();
$array[0] = $this;
$array[1] = 'loader';
spl_autoload_register($array);
```

Answer (score 0):

Well it hands over a single parameter to the function `spl_autoload_register()`. The parameter is of type `array` and contains two elements. The first one is the object that calls the function, the second is a string.

Answer (score 0):

```
some_function(array($this, 'something'))
```

is just a function you call and as parameter you give it an array

it could be rewritten to this

```
some_function([$this, 'something'])
```

or

```
$arr = array($this, 'something');
some_function($arr);
```